# How to sort a very large data array by multiple parameter in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, database, sorting

Example:

```
[{id:1,name:'Jhon',age:'31',address:'XYZ',mobile:'012345678',department:3,section:2,designation:2,.............(34 Types Data)},..........(almost count in 10546)]
```

From this data I want them all ascending first in department then section then designation then name then if multiple same name then go with id. Almost sort like the sequence tree given below.

```
department=>
|--section=>
|----designation=>
|------name=>
|--------id=>
```

I have tried the following one but sequence still not same all time.

```
reurnData.sort(function(a, b) {
  var pA1 = a.section;
  var pA2 = b.section;
  var pB1 = a.department;
  var pB2 = b.department;
  var pC1 = a.designation;
  var pC2 = b.designation;
  var pD1 = a.name;
  var pD2 = b.name;
  var pE1 = a.id;
  var pE2 = b.id;

  if (pA1 < pA2) return -1;
  if (pA1 > pA2) return 1;
  if (pB1 < pB2) return -1;
  if (pB1 > pB2) return 1;
  if (pC1 < pC2) return -1;
  if (pC1 > pC2) return 1;
  if (pD1 < pD2) return -1;
  if (pD1 > pD2) return 1;
  if (pE1 < pE2) return -1;
  if (pE1 > pE2) return 1;
  return 0;
});
```

Comment: How do you determine that the sequence is different?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem with your code applied to random data: https://repl.it/G1kF. The sort order is always the same.

Answer (score 4):

You could chain the whole sorting criteria.

It goes through the deltas until a delta is found, which is not zero. Then the difference of the comparing gets returned, as needed for [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

```
array.sort(function (a, b) {
    return (
        a.department - b.department ||
        a.section - b.section ||
        a.designation - b.designation ||
        a.name.localeCompare(b.name) ||
        a.id - b.id
    );
});
```

Answer (score 2):

@nina-cholz could solve your problem,and I'd like give you another solution,that is more little complex but easy to use.then you can use it as:`array.sort(by("department,section,designation,name,id"))`

### the code beolow:

```
function by(columns) {
    columns = typeof columns == "string" ? columns.split(",") : columns;

    function compare(a, b) {
        return a > b ? 1 : a < b ? -1 : 0;
    }

    return function (a, b) {
        for (var i in columns) {
            var p = columns[i];
            var it = compare(a[p], b[p]);
            if (it) {
                return it;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

### Examples / Tests

```
test("sort with single column", () => {
    let array = [{a: 1}, {a: 3}, {a: 2}];

    expect(array.sort(by("a"))).toEqual([{a: 1}, {a: 2}, {a: 3}]);
});

test("sort column with null values", () => {
    let array = [{a: 1}, {a: null}];

    expect(array.sort(by("a"))).toEqual([{a: null}, {a: 1}]);
});

test("sort string type column", () => {
    let array = [{a: "foo"}, {a: "bar"}];

    expect(array.sort(by("a"))).toEqual([{a: "bar"}, {a: "foo"}]);
});

test("sort by string columns", () => {
    let array = [{a: 1, b: 2}, {a: 1, b: 1}];

    expect(array.sort(by("a,b"))).toEqual([{a: 1, b: 1}, {a: 1, b: 2}]);
});

test("sort by array columns", () => {
    let array = [{a: 1, b: 2}, {a: 1, b: 1}];

    expect(array.sort(by(["a", "b"]))).toEqual([{a: 1, b: 1}, {a: 1, b: 2}]);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question.

I think it deserves a dynamic solution that should be valid for sorting according to any number of properties supplied in an order of priority. Let's create a factory to give us an array of fake objects in length `n`.

```js
function getFakeObjects(n){  // helper function to get test objects
  return Array(n).fill()
                 .reduce(o => o.concat({p1 : String.fromCharCode(...Array(5).fill().map(_ => ~~(Math.random()*26)+97)),
                                        p2 : ~~(Math.random()*5)+1,
                                        p3 : ["Istanbul","Moscow","New York","Tokyo","Rio","Accra"][~~(Math.random()*6)],
                                        p4 : ~~(Math.random()*2+1)+String.fromCharCode(~~(Math.random()*3)+65)
                                       }),[]);
}

function multiLevelSorter(os,ps){
  return os.sort(function(a,b){
                   var p = ps.find(f => a[f] !== b[f]);
                   return a[p] < b[p] ? -1 : 1;
                 });
}

var fakes = getFakeObjects(50),
sortOrder = ["p3","p2","p4","p1"],
   sorted = multiLevelSorter(fakes,sortOrder);
sorted.forEach(o => console.log("{p1:", o.p1,"p2:",o.p2,"p3:",o.p3,"p4:",o.p4,"}"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```